# Fetching specific dict values via Python script/code

Tags: python

I am performing a RESTAPI call via Python and fetching value in dict format after performing json.loads call.

Challenge is, I would like to fetch the below values:

a) 'checksum': 'f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726'

b) 'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA' (All zone-names available in output)

I tried lot of ways to fetch via .get() methods and it wasn't much helpful.
Moreover, it's not a proper dict datatype and that's another challenge.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
global switch_config_backup_json
call_config_backup = ""
try:
    switch_config_url = 'http://' + ipaddress + '/rest/running/brocade-zone/effective-configuration'
    switch_config_backup_call_headers = {'Authorization': custom_api_key, 'Accept': 'application/yang-data+json', 'Content-Type': 'application/yang-data+json'}
    call_config_backup = requests.get(url=switch_config_url, headers=switch_config_backup_call_headers)
    switch_config_backup_dict = json.loads(call_config_backup.content)
    print("Switch zone and members data backup:\n", switch_config_backup_dict)
```

Value Retrieved: (Dict Type)

{'Response': {'effective-configuration': {'default-zone-access': 1, 'cfg-action': 0, 'db-max': 1045274, 'db-avail': 1041908, 'db-committed': 1268, 'db-transaction': 0, 'db-chassis-wide-committed': 2280, 'transaction-token': 0, 'checksum': 'f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726', 'cfg-name': 'b238638', 'enabled-zone': [{'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740A', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:71']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740C', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:e3']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA_Test', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPB', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge-Dellpr730H', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '10:00:00:10:9b:26:3f:fb']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge_Dellpr730E', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '10:00:00:90:fa:02:4c:c4']}}, {'zone-name': 'dellpr730B_Marge', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cc', '21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cd', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:19', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:5d']}}]}}}

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not a proper dict datatype"?

Comment: what did you try? It seems you has dictionary with lists - so it may need also indexes or `for`-loop to get data from list - and using only `get()` can't resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `dictionary` with `list` so you will need `for`-loop (or indexes ie. `[0]`) to get values.

And because you have nested `dictionares` so you will have to use all keys to get nested value.

```
data = {'Response': {'effective-configuration': {'default-zone-access': 1, 'cfg-action': 0, 'db-max': 1045274, 'db-avail': 1041908, 'db-committed': 1268, 'db-transaction': 0, 'db-chassis-wide-committed': 2280, 'transaction-token': 0, 'checksum': 'f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726', 'cfg-name': 'b238638', 'enabled-zone': [{'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740A', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:71']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740C', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:e3']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA_Test', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPB', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge-Dellpr730H', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '10:00:00:10:9b:26:3f:fb']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge_Dellpr730E', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '10:00:00:90:fa:02:4c:c4']}}, {'zone-name': 'dellpr730B_Marge', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cc', '21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cd', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:19', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:5d']}}]}}}

#print('[DEBUG] type:', type(data) )
#print('[DEBUG] keys:', data.keys() )

#print('[DEBUG] type:', type(data['Response']) )
#print('[DEBUG] keys:', data['Response'].keys() )

#print('[DEBUG] type:', type(data['Response']['effective-configuration']) )
#print('[DEBUG] keys:', data['Response']['effective-configuration'].keys() )

checksum = data['Response']['effective-configuration']['checksum']
print('checksum:', checksum)

zones = data['Response']['effective-configuration']['enabled-zone']
print('type:', type(zones))

for item in zones:
    print('zone-name:', item['zone-name'])
```

Result:

```
checksum: f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726
type: <class 'list'>
zone-name: Axel_Dellpr740A
zone-name: Axel_Dellpr740C
zone-name: Axel_Rodge_SPA
zone-name: Axel_Rodge_SPA_Test
zone-name: Axel_Rodge_SPB
zone-name: Rodge-Dellpr730H
zone-name: Rodge_Dellpr730E
zone-name: dellpr730B_Marge
```

---

**BTW:**

You could use `json.dumps(..., indent=...)` to format it with indentations to better see what you have in `JSON`.

If you see `{...}` then it is (nested) `dictionary`, if you see `[...]` then it is (nested) `list`.

You can also use `type(item)` to test if you have (nested) `dictionary` or `list`.
And for `dictionary` you can use `item.keys()` to see keys which you can use on this level.

```
data = {'Response': {'effective-configuration': {'default-zone-access': 1, 'cfg-action': 0, 'db-max': 1045274, 'db-avail': 1041908, 'db-committed': 1268, 'db-transaction': 0, 'db-chassis-wide-committed': 2280, 'transaction-token': 0, 'checksum': 'f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726', 'cfg-name': 'b238638', 'enabled-zone': [{'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740A', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:71']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Dellpr740C', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:e3']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPA_Test', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Axel_Rodge_SPB', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge-Dellpr730H', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '10:00:00:10:9b:26:3f:fb']}}, {'zone-name': 'Rodge_Dellpr730E', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45', '50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45', '10:00:00:90:fa:02:4c:c4']}}, {'zone-name': 'dellpr730B_Marge', 'zone-type': 0, 'member-entry': {'entry-name': ['21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cc', '21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cd', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:19', '50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:5d']}}]}}}

import json

text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "effective-configuration": {
      "default-zone-access": 1,
      "cfg-action": 0,
      "db-max": 1045274,
      "db-avail": 1041908,
      "db-committed": 1268,
      "db-transaction": 0,
      "db-chassis-wide-committed": 2280,
      "transaction-token": 0,
      "checksum": "f9676703bba1f3ac726de1445de27726",
      "cfg-name": "b238638",
      "enabled-zone": [
        {
          "zone-name": "Axel_Dellpr740A",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8",
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8",
              "10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:71"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Axel_Dellpr740C",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8",
              "50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8",
              "10:00:00:10:9b:58:31:e3"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Axel_Rodge_SPA",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8",
              "50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Axel_Rodge_SPA_Test",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:63:08:60:1d:e8",
              "50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Axel_Rodge_SPB",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:1d:e8",
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Rodge-Dellpr730H",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45",
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45",
              "10:00:00:10:9b:26:3f:fb"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "Rodge_Dellpr730E",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "50:06:01:6b:08:60:0f:45",
              "50:06:01:63:08:64:0f:45",
              "10:00:00:90:fa:02:4c:c4"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "zone-name": "dellpr730B_Marge",
          "zone-type": 0,
          "member-entry": {
            "entry-name": [
              "21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cc",
              "21:00:00:24:ff:17:19:cd",
              "50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:19",
              "50:00:09:75:a8:1d:40:5d"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You simple suggestion and code snippet helped me to a great extent. Thanks for the help and support.